# Custom module library not detected

Tags: 7, javascript

I am writing a custom module to load the crossfilter.js library in Drupal 7. I have followed what I believe are the right steps to doing that when using the Libraries module API.
However when I run `drush libraries-list` all I get for my library is 'not detected'

Below is my sample code. I intend to load version 1.3.7 of the library and already I have a directory called `crossfilter` and I have the crossfilter.js and crossfilter.min.js files in that directory.

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

```
function crossfilter_libraries_info() {
$libraries['crossfilter'] = array(
  'name' => 'Crossfilter JS',
  'description' => 'Crossfilter JS integration for Drupal',
  'download url' => 'https://github.com/square/crossfilter/archive/master.zip',
  'vendor url' => 'http://square.github.io/crossfilter/',
  'version arguments' => array(
      'file' => 'crossfilter.min.js',
      'pattern' => '/version="(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"/',
   ),
  'files' => array(
      'js' => array('crossfilter.min.js'),
    ),
  'variants' => array(
      'source' => array(
          'files' => array(
              'js' => array('crossfilter.js')
            ),
        ),
    ),

);
return $libraries;
```

}

Comment: This code looks fine to me. Can you confirm the files are at /sites/libraries/crossfilter/*.js? You could also try to reinstall the module with devel module. Perhaps Drupal has not found the hook yet.

Comment: Did you mean /sites/all/libraries/crossfilter/*.js? I do have the files in place and still getting the same error. Let me try the devel approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your version regex ist wrong. According to the [source code](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/blob/master/crossfilter.js), the version string looks like this:

```
crossfilter.version = "1.3.7";
```

The regex pattern needs to account for the whitespace around the equal-sign. I'd probably write it like this

```
'pattern' => '/crossfilter\.version\s*=\s*"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"/',
```

Comment: That was the gotcha plus the file. I can pick the version from crossfilter.js and not crossfilter.min.js.